# Intent data not updated in activity while launched from Android push notification click

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I looked for a solution for my problem and couldn't find anything. My app is using GCM and some of the pushes that I send are wrong (sometimes the Intent's data is not updated, it's the same as the previous one).

I sent push notification using the following payload:

```
{
   "registration_ids" : ["dS9iBOAXlWc:APA9..."],
    "notification" : {
        "title" : "Hey",
        "body" : "This is the body"
    },
   "data" : {
       // my data
   }
}
```

The Notification is generated by the system when the Application is in the background and it is what I want. I process the data this way:

```
public class MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        Intent activityIntent = activity.getIntent();
        if (null != activityIntent && null != activityIntent.getExtras()) {
            // process activityIntent.getExtras();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working well except in one particular set of events:

1. I killed the app and sent a push notification P1.
2. I received a Notification with its data after I clicked on the Notification.
3. I closed the app by pressing the home button.
4. I sent myself another push notification P2.
5. I clicked the received notification and here is my bug: the data is P1's data, not P2's.

How can I clear this Intent? and make the GCM Receiver update it?

### Edit 1:

After more research, it really looks like a FCM or Android bug. 
When my app is in the background and I click on a notification, a new Activity is created. But following the steps I described, the same activity is resumed:

After kill, on notification click:

```
11-16 10:10:35.434 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest W/ActivityLifecycle: onActivityCreated: com.zinfroy.intentstest.MainActivity@c14c125

11-16 10:10:35.517 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest D/MainActivity#onCreate: Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1479287431249234%162dc7d9162dc7d9

11-16 10:10:35.521 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest W/ActivityLifecycle: onActivityStarted: com.zinfroy.intentstest.MainActivity@c14c125
11-16 10:10:35.522 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest D/ActivityLifecycle#onStarted: Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1479287431249234%162dc7d9162dc7d9

11-16 10:10:35.525 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest W/ActivityLifecycle: onActivityResumed: com.zinfroy.intentstest.MainActivity@c14c125
11-16 10:10:35.525 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest D/ActivityLifecycle#onResumed: Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1479287431249234%162dc7d9162dc7d9

11-16 10:10:35.526 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest D/MainActivity#onResume: Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1479287431249234%162dc7d9162dc7d9
```

Click on Home button:

```
11-16 10:13:12.366 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest W/ActivityLifecycle: onActivityPaused: com.zinfroy.intentstest.MainActivity@c14c125

11-16 10:13:12.406 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest W/ActivityLifecycle: onActivitySaveInstanceState: com.zinfroy.intentstest.MainActivity@c14c125
11-16 10:13:12.406 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest D/ActivityLifecycle#saveInstance: Key: com.google.firebase.analytics.screen_service Value: Bundle[{referrer_name=MainActivity, id=-7274484894154241509, name=null}]

11-16 10:13:12.408 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest W/ActivityLifecycle: onActivityStopped: com.zinfroy.intentstest.MainActivity@c14c125
```

Click on notification:

**The is no `onActivityCreated` here!**

```
11-16 10:13:22.342 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest W/ActivityLifecycle: onActivityStarted: com.zinfroy.intentstest.MainActivity@c14c125
11-16 10:13:22.342 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest D/ActivityLifecycle#onStarted: Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1479287431249234%162dc7d9162dc7d9

11-16 10:13:22.342 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest W/ActivityLifecycle: onActivityResumed: com.zinfroy.intentstest.MainActivity@c14c125
11-16 10:13:22.343 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest D/ActivityLifecycle#onResumed: Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1479287431249234%162dc7d9162dc7d9

11-16 10:13:22.344 24132-24132/com.zinfroy.intentstest D/MainActivity#onResume: Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1479287431249234%162dc7d9162dc7d9
```

So as the same Activity is resumed, the same Intent is read :/

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, what device are you seeing this on and are you able to reproduce this behavior on multiple devices?

Comment: I tried on a Nexus 6p (Android N), Samsung galaxy 7(M) and Samsung A3 (M) and i could reproduce everytime. I updated the steps to reproduce the bug.